# Modifying E-mail through shell on Sharepoint 2013

Tags: user

I have working Sharepoint 2010 script that modifies e-mail for the web site user. The problem is - the script doesn't work on Sharepoint 2013. I am not able to modify its e-mail. I tried to modify it through Profile Synchronization with AD, but no luck. Then I got this script, but it seems that it works only on SP 2010. Any ideas?
What I want to achieve is modified user's contact card, with modified e-mail, at Site Settings -> People and Groups -> web-site Members

```
cls  
$web =Get-SPWeb http://sp2013/sites/wooly/
$list=$web.Lists["User Information List"]
$user =$list.GetItemById(##)
$user["SipAddress"]=""
$user["EMail"]="hoover@test.pst"
$user.update()
$list.update()

$web.update()
```

Answer (score 3):

I could add/change the user’s missing email address using PowerShell. Here is the code that I used:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell
$web = get-spweb "SiteCollection URL" 
$user = $web.EnsureUser("domain\username") 
echo $user
Set-SPUser -Identity $user -Email "email@yourdomain.com" -Web "SiteCollection URL"
Remove-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
```

put the above code in Windows Powershell ISE and execute it.

If you provide a valid user name, echo $user command will display the user's display name and user's login,

**Note** that if you have many site collections you may need to make this change for each one (give the site collection URL in the -web option).

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Hi I wrote PS C:\Users\administrator.CMBUQA> Set-SPUser -Identity "testqa\katarina1" -Email "dimitri@testqa.pst" -Web http://sp2013/sites/wooly/  and I am getting error
"Set-SPUser : You must specify a valid user object or user identity."  Does this mean I have the wrong user, or non-existing user?

Comment: to check for the valid user name, use the below command, after checking it, you can change the email id of a particular user." $web = get-spweb https://sharepointdns/site/site $web.EnsureUser("DOMAIN\user") "

Comment: System is not able to find the specified user, it could be wrong user or non-existing user.

Comment: PS C:\Users\administrator.TESTQA>  $web = get-spweb http://sp2013/sites/wooly $w
eb.EnsureUser("TESTQA\katarina1")
Get-SPWeb : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument
'i:0#.w|testqa\katarina1'.
At line:1 char:9
+  $web = get-spweb http://sp2013/sites/wooly
$web.EnsureUser("TESTQA\katarina1")
+
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-SPWeb], ParameterBindi
   ngException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.SharePoint
   .PowerShell.SPCmdletGetWeb

Comment: Any ideas why I am getting this error?

Comment: I have modified the code, please use the latest one.

Comment: Thanks Karthik for helping me. I don't get errors any more, but I still have issues. Basically I don't see update in contact card for the site user. What I want to see is different e-mail and SIP addresses in contact card. Please see links for details [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/348072)  and [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/348071)

Comment: Hi Karthik, I just double checked your script. It does modify e-mail address, but it also modifies IM address on contact card at the same time, which is not something I want

Comment: Thanks @KarthikJaganathan for the script. Worked for me. Just one small comment below line in your script could make use of the variable.   <br> Set-SPUser -Identity $user -Email "email@yourdomain.com" -Web $web